# realloc twice doesn't work on visual studio

Tags: c++, c

Can you tell me why this doesn't work on Visual Studio?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    //dynamic memory allocation
     char** document = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    //lets increase the double pointer document's size. now it has document[0] and document[1]
    document = (char**)realloc(document, 2 * sizeof(char*));

    //now let's increase the size of the document[1] to twice bigger so that it will have document[1][0] and document[0][0] 
    document[1] = (char*)realloc(document[1], 2 * sizeof(char)); // this give error.

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Does it return NULL? What exactly? Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't realloc `document[1]`  You didn't allocate that pointer.  It's at best an undefined value.

Comment: it gives 'Access violation reading' error.

Comment: however, i create the document[1] by document = (char**)realloc(document, 2 * sizeof(char*));

Comment: Now you have undefined memory address pointing to a newly allocated address.

Comment: Another way to learn pointer and memory management in C is to just avoid using `realloc` until you get the hang of malloc, pointers, and releationships to arrays.  realloc is effectively shorthand for allocating a new pointer, copying the bytes from the old address to the new address, and freeing the old address.

Comment: Please also note that you should not use `realloc` (or `malloc`/`free`/`calloc`) in C++ code. You tagged both languages, so it is not clear which one you are actually writing.

Comment: `document[1]` is not initialised by the first `realloc()`.   Accessing its value in order to pass it to the second `realloc()`   (i.e to `realloc(document[1], 2*sizeof(char))` ) therefore gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not assign any value to `document[1]` before you called `realloc(document[1], 2 * sizeof(char));`. The additional memory that `realloc` allocates is not initialized to any value.

Therefore the value of `document[1]` will be *indeterminate* at this point and using indeterminate values in most situations causes *undefined behavior*.

Anyway, even if the value wasn't indeterminate, you can only pass a pointer that was returned from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` or a null pointer value to `realloc`. Otherwise, again, your program has *undefined behavior*.

While `document`'s value is a pointer returned by `malloc`/`realloc`, `document[1]`'s value is certainly not a pointer returned by either of the mentioned functions or a null pointer, because you didn't assign either of these to it.

To make what you are trying to do work, you need to either set `document[1]` to `NULL` before the `realloc` call (in which case `realloc` will behave like `malloc`) or use `malloc` instead. Given that the first variant would be just a more complex way of writing the latter, I suggest you just use `malloc`.

Comment: A `NULL` pointer can be passed to `realloc()`.    Otherwise, you're correct - the undefined behaviour is due to passing an uninitialised `document[1]` as the first argument of `realloc()`.

Comment: @Peter Right, I forgot to mention that. I have updated the answer.